# Can't access to class from .php file (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, namespaces, phpstorm

Sorry for stupid question, but I really don't understand what's wrong.

I have a separate class `User` and want to make its object in .php file. I went to `Settings/Directories` and marked folder users like Source also added a prefix(PSR-4). In Test.php I imported needed class.

But the result is the same:

> Fatal error: Class 'Users\User' not found in E:\Server\Apache24\htdocs\lab1\users\Test.php on line 10

User.php:

```
<?php
namespace Users;

class User
{
    var $name;
    var $login;
    var $password;
}
```

Test.php:

```
<?php

use Users\User;

$user1 = new User;
```

[image: Settings/Directories]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change test.php

```
<?php
require_once('user.php');
use Users\User;

$user1 = new User;
```